# Delete a value with between two values

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Can be a little complicated, but I tried very hard and get the result. I'm getting the video links from a site with HtmlAgilityPack.

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(@"C:\Users\e9396\Desktop\r.html");
foreach (HtmlNode links in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
    if (links.NextSibling != null)
    {
        ArrayList ArrayLinksList = new ArrayList();
        ArrayLinksList.Add(links.Attributes["href"].Value);
        listbox.Items.AddRange(ArrayLinksList.ToArray());
    }
}
```

But some of the links are as follows.

```html
/video/93409905175
/dk?cmd=VideoVitrinaPopup&amp;st.redirect=myVideo&amp;st.vvp_cmd=VideoVitrinaPopupMovieEdit&amp;st.vv_movieId=93409905175&amp;st.cmd=userMain
/video/93361801751
/dk?cmd=VideoVitrinaPopup&amp;st.redirect=myVideo&amp;st.vvp_cmd=VideoVitrinaPopupMovieEdit&amp;st.vv_movieId=93361801751&amp;st.cmd=userMain
/video/93442476567
/dk?cmd=VideoVitrinaPopup&amp;st.redirect=myVideo&amp;st.vvp_cmd=VideoVitrinaPopupMovieEdit&amp;st.vv_movieId=93442476567&amp;st.cmd=userMain
/video/93409839639
/dk?cmd=VideoVitrinaPopup&amp;st.redirect=myVideo&amp;st.vvp_cmd=VideoVitrinaPopupMovieEdit&amp;st.vv_movieId=93409839639&amp;st.cmd=userMain
/video/93442411031
/dk?cmd=VideoVitrinaPopup&amp;st.redirect=myVideo&amp;st.vvp_cmd=VideoVitrinaPopupMovieEdit&amp;st.vv_movieId=93442411031&amp;st.cmd=userMain
/video/93442345495
/dk?cmd=VideoVitrinaPopup&amp;st.redirect=myVideo&amp;st.vvp_cmd=VideoVitrinaPopupMovieEdit&amp;st.vv_movieId=93442345495&amp;st.cmd=userMain
/video/93461940759
/dk?cmd=VideoVitrinaPopup&amp;st.redirect=myVideo&amp;st.vvp_cmd=VideoVitrinaPopupMovieEdit&amp;st.vv_movieId=93461940759&amp;st.cmd=userMain
```

links like this "/video/93409905175" OK.

But i want to delete links like this

> "/video/93409905175 /dk?cmd=VideoVitrinaPopup&st.redirect=myVideo&st.vvp_cmd=VideoVitrinaPopupMovieEdit&st.vv_movieId=**93409905175**&st.cmd=userMain".

I can't erase it because of the ID in bold the marked locations.

I want to be like that, thanks.

```html
/video/93409905175
/video/93361801751
/video/93442476567
/video/93409839639
/video/93442411031
/video/93442345495
/video/93461940759
```

Comment: Why not remove the links in the if statement, adding if the `url.Contains("dk?")`?

Comment: @cDima I don't know, I tried to get just the links. You can check it [this](http://hizliresim.eyuperdogan.com.tr/files/t7N2U3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> FilterLinks(HtmlDocument doc, string regexFilter)
{
    var regex = new Regex(regexFilter);
    return doc.DocumentNode
        .SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
        .Where( n => n.NextSibling != null && 
                regex.IsMatch(n.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty)))
        .Select(n => n.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty));
}
```

Call it like this:

```
foreach(var link in FilterLinks(doc, @"^\/video\/[0-9]*")) listbox.Items.Add(link);
```

Comment: getting error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection'

Comment: listbox.Items.AddRange(FilterLinks(doc, @"^\/video\/[0-9]*").ToArray()); or something like that. It's a generic kind of list that you can enumerate over.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for progress Travis Sharp, but the type of the value returned by the procedure FilterLinks the links are probably not suitable.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> FilterLinks(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc, string regexFilter)
{
    var regex = new Regex(regexFilter);
    return doc.DocumentNode
              .SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
              .Where(n => n.NextSibling != null 
                       && regex.IsMatch(n.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty)))
              .Select(n => n.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty));
}
```

FilterLinks we get the returned value from a variable.
And we call it like this:

```
var xLinkeler = FilterLinks(doc, @"^\/video\/[0-9]*");
foreach (var iett in xLinkeler)
{
    listbox.Items.Add(iett);
}
```

Comment: True - FilterLinks provides an accurate end result. All that is needed is to call FilterLinks(...).ToArray() or FilterLinks.ToList() and it should produce the desired object type.